# CSS floats messed up

Tags: css, html, css-float

It doesn't stay where I want it, look at this:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 30%">
 <img src="{avatar}" alt="" />
</div>

<div style="float:right; width: 70%; text-align: left">
 {message}
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

**Internet Explorer:**
[image]

**Mozilla Firefox:**
[image]

I want the text to be in the top (tried vertical-align: top), and i'd like the image to be in the white box in IE.

Hope someone more skilled can help me out.

Thanks!
Can't figure out the problem :/

## Edit: Added whole code

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

body {
font: 11px Geneva, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
width: 999px;
background: #EFEFEF;
}

#content {
width: 400px;
}

.thread-content {
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #CECFCE;
background: #FFF;
}

div.header {
border: 1px solid #CECFCE;
background: #FFF;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}


<div id="content">

<div class="header">{title}</div>
<div class="thread-content">

<div style="float: left; width: 30%; padding: 5px">
 <img src="{avatar}" alt="user avatar" />
</div>

<div style="float: right; width: 70%; text-align: left">
 {message}
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the html / css for the parent container element as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure the margin of both are set to 0:

```
<img src="{avatar}" alt=""  style="float: left; width: 30%; margin: 0px"/> 

<div style="float:right; width: 70%; text-align: left; margin: 0px">
 {message}
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

As css can be really tricky, some other solutions to try:

- Let both float left, should make no difference.
- Make sure the border doesn't increase the size.
- Descrease the width of one a bit, IE is stubborn.

Comment: Edited slightly. Always remove unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the sum of the (external) widths of the two floating divs is larger than the internal width of the external box, so they don't fit in the same row.

Try increasing the width of the external div, decreasing its padding, decreasing the width or margin or padding of the internal boxes.

Comment: 70% + 30% = 100%... means an exact fit. Makes me think.

Comment: Not in CSS world. That's the "beauty" of CSS box model.

Comment: Yeah, true... padding and border can destroy layouts with ease.

Comment: In CSS, the `width` property measures the internal width of an element (*excluding* the padding, border, and margin).  You're trying to line up external width (*including* the padding, border, and margin).  What you're ending up with is a total external width of 70% + 30% + div1-padding + div1-border + div1-margin + *etc.*  If the padding, border, and margin don't total 0 (margins can be negative), they'll be too wide.

Comment: Not if you have margins or paddings or borders. See http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/  for an explanation of the box model.

Answer (score 0):

Code works fine when I tried it. You sure there isn't any padding or margin on the image or the text? That would mess up the percentages you're using. If you have it examine the image and text in Firebug to see what styles are being applied.

Answer (score 0):

When you say width: 30% or width: 70% it implies the width of the content inside the div excluding the padding, border and margin of the div. Looking at the images I am sure you have added some padding etc to both divs. Also I do not see any 'background: #fff' in your code, so I am not sure which one is the 'white' box.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, did I get voted down because I used a table?
I am not by trade a designer, I am actually a programmer and I know there are hard-core css designers that cringe at the idea of using a table layout but it seems to works for me. The graphic designers that I work with give auto generated table layout from fireworks to work with which is a real pain.

Anyway the way I personally would try to accomplish the dersired effect though pure css would be more like.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SandBox</title>  
    <style type="text/css">
        #outerDiv
        {
            margin:0;
            background-image:url(myImage.gif);
            background-position:top left;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            padding-left:30%;
            min-height:200px;
            background-color:#777777;               
        }
        #innerDiv
        {
            background-color:#333333;
        }
    </style>     
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width:500px;">
        <div id="outerDiv">
            <div id="innerDiv">content goes here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note: I am not a designer. I also made this a wiki. So please edit or at least leave a comment if you going to vote down.